# Нужно ли обособлять уточняющий оборот с "даже"?

Tags: пунктуация

Конечно, есть конструктивные решения проблемы, но, во-первых, они не реализованы в конструкциях завода, а во-вторых, без пропускных характеристик, даже в случаях их реализации (,) приходилось бы поднастройку клапанов производить методом «профессора» с известной фамилией.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, есть конструктивные решения проблемы, но, во-первых, они не реализованы в конструкциях завода, а во-вторых, без пропускных характеристик, даже в случаях их реализации приходилось бы поднастройку клапанов производить методом «профессора» с известной фамилией.

Обособление нежелательно, получаются два рядом расположенных обособленных члена, отчего теряется логическая мысль сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

"даже в случаях" и "приходилось бы" - как-то слишком громоздко.
"... , даже в случае их реализации пришлось бы поднастройку..."
Запятая здесь не нужна, она разрывает текст. Нет необходимости нарочито обособлять фразу "даже в случае их реализации". Но если автор придаёт этой фразе какое-то особое значение, что-то хочет ей подчеркнуть, то запятую поставить можно.

Comment: Но перед "даже" запятая нужна, конечно.

Comment: Представим себе упрощённый вариант Вашего текста: " Есть конструктивные решения проблемы, но даже в случае их реализации... Здесь "даже в случае их реализации" не нуждается в обособлении.

Answer (score 0):

> Конечно, есть конструктивные решения проблемы, но, во-первых, они не
>   реализованы в конструкциях завода, а во-вторых, без пропускных
>   характеристик, даже в случаях **их** реализации…

Предложение нужно перестроить.

**Вариант:**

*Конечно, есть конструктивные решения проблемы, но, во-первых, они не реализованы в конструкциях завода, а во-вторых, даже если бы они были реализованы...*

**P.S.**

"Конструктивные" и "в конструкциях", конечно, не очень-то хорошо смотрятся в одном предложении, но, не зная контекста, лучшего пока предложить не могу.